# Run Apple Script File (.scpt) from TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, mac, scripts

Is there a possibility to run an Apple Script File (.scpt) directly from TexMaker in macOS?

**EDIT:**
My intention is to delete all not used data like .log, .acr ... to be able to share the raw .tex and .bib data with my colleagues who don't use tex right now. I saw some other post to this topic but I would like to do it my way. By the way: My Apple Script is ready to go and I would like to use it...

Comment: I suspect not, since TeXMaker is a crossplatform app that does not use the Cocoa API. But if it can run shell scripts, it's possible to call an Applescript from a shell script, so maybe you can.

Comment: Since TeXMaker uses Javascript for scripting, it may be possible. See discussion here: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/using-javascript-for-automation-from-applescript-and-vice-versa/4054/10

Comment: You could also use Automator to create a service for texmaker which executes the applescript. Maybe you could add to your question what the apple script is supposed to do.

Comment: I don't know if this is also true for texmaker, but texstudio has a build functionality to clean up a customisable list of files.

Comment: That would be the best, but I can't find anything in TexMaker

Comment: @Passe Texstudio is very similar, try it :)

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for this hint, I just saw some screenshots but it seems to be very similar! I will give it a try.

Comment: @Passe Texstudio has started as a fork of texmaker. Since then some nice functionalities have been added.